# Facing Parse Error Issue in my running site

Tags: php, html, wordpress, frontend, cpanel

My running site is blocked due to an error and I don't know what's the issue is, the error  `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/content/62/11926462/html/wp-includes/pomo/mo.php on line 11`

[image: a]

Comment: Please paste the relevant code here.

Comment: `foreach([5,27,17,24] as $I){
       $zhKCdRnW8701 .= $EKwVrQip9212[$I];
    }
` @Pupil line 11 has this loop

Answer (score 0):

Short hand array syntax (`[]` instead of `array()`) is introduced in [PHP 5.4](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php).

> Short array syntax has been added, e.g. $a = [1, 2, 3, 4]; or $a =
>   ['one' => 1, 'two' => 2, 'three' => 3, 'four' => 4];.

In your case, `array()` should be used.

Modify the line:

```
foreach([5,27,17,24] as $I){ $zhKCdRnW8701 .= $EKwVrQip9212[$I]; }
```

As

```
foreach(array(5,27,17,24) as $I){ $zhKCdRnW8701 .= $EKwVrQip9212[$I]; }
```

Comment: After this my site is showing blank page

Comment: There should be another error. The above line does not have any error.